# Derivative of the Laplace Transform

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

I calculated that $$ \mathcal{L}'[f(t)] = \mathcal{L}[f'(t)]-s\mathcal{L}[f(t)] $$ And if I try to substitute some values for f(t) I always get zero. So, how do I demonstrate that it gives, or doesn't always give, zero?

Comment: Can you show us how you got that formula? And can you show us how you get zero when you use it? There are not enough details right now to know what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to note that the Laplace transform is a linear operator, which means it satisfies the following properties for any functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$:

$\mathcal{L}[af(t) + bg(t)] = a\mathcal{L}[f(t)] + b\mathcal{L}[g(t)]$ (where $a$ and $b$ are constants)
$\mathcal{L}[f'(t)] = s\mathcal{L}[f(t)] - f(0)$
Using these properties, we can simplify the expression for $\mathcal{L}'[f(t)]$ as follows:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}'[f(t)] &= \mathcal{L}[f'(t)] - s\mathcal{L}[f(t)] \
&= (s\mathcal{L}[f(t)] - f(0)) - s\mathcal{L}[f(t)] \quad\quad \text{(using property 2)}\
&= -f(0)
\end{align*}

Therefore, we can see that $\mathcal{L}'[f(t)]$ is not always zero. It depends on the value of $f(0)$.

For example, if $f(t) = \sin(t)$, then $f(0) = 0$ and $\mathcal{L}'[f(t)] = 0$. However, if $f(t) = \cos(t)$, then $f(0) = 1$ and $\mathcal{L}'[f(t)] = -1$.